# How I can inherit only 2 of 4 attributes of an parent class?

Tags: python

I am getting this error:
TypeError: **init**() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'descripcion' and 'precio'

I don't know why is this happening, the class "Alimentos" works pretty well I guess it is because I inherited every single attribute from the parent class "Producto". Then the class "Libros" and the class "Medicamentos" are having troubles, in Pycharm I get this message in those lines:

Parameter 'descripcion' unfilled
Parameter 'precio' unfilled

Hope you can help me!

```
    def __init__(self, referencia, nombre, descripcion, precio):
        self.referencia = referencia
        self.nombre = nombre
        self.descripcion = descripcion
        self.precio = precio

    def precio_mayor_10(self):
        if self.precio > 10:
            print("Este producto tiene un precio mayor a 10")


class Alimentos(Producto):
    def __init__(self, referencia, nombre, descripcion, precio, productor, distribuidor):
        #This Super works fine
        super().__init__(referencia, nombre,descripcion, precio)

        self.productor = productor
        self.distribuidor = distribuidor

class Libros(Producto):
    def __init__(self, referencia, precio, nombre_libro, nombre_autor, isbn, distribuidor):
        #Here I want to inherit only the "referencia" and "precio" attributes
        super().__init__(referencia, precio)

        self.nombre_libro = nombre_libro
        self.nombre_autor = nombre_autor
        self.isbn = isbn
        self.distribuidor = distribuidor

class Medicamentos(Producto):
    def __init__(self, nombre, precio, distribuidora, farmaceutica):
        #Here I want to inherit only the "referencia" and "precio" attributes
        super().__init__(nombre, precio)

        self.distribuidora = distribuidora
        self.farmaceutica = farmaceutica


Alimento1 = Alimentos(4343, "papa","Tubérculo", 2, "ProductorXYZ", "DistribuidorXYZ")
Alimento2 = Alimentos(4923, "Zanahoria","Hortaliza", 11, "ProductorXYZ", "DistribuidorXYZ")
Alimento3 = Alimentos(9343, "Caraota","Legumbre", 10, "ProductorXYZ", "DistribuidorXYZ")

Alimento1.precio_mayor_10()
Alimento2.precio_mayor_10()
Alimento3.precio_mayor_10()

Libro1 = Libros(3434, 50, "Harry Potter", "J. K. Rowling", "843843", "DistribuidoraXYZ")
Libro2 = Libros(7424, 9, "Pepito el alegre", "Juan Pérez", "390402", "DistribuidoraXYZ")

Libro1.precio_mayor_10()
Libro2.precio_mayor_10()

Medicamento1 = Medicamentos("Aspirina", 15, "DistribuidoraXYZ", "FarmaceuticaXYZ" )

Medicamento1.precio_mayor_10()
```

Comment: You always inherit all of the attributes.  The `Products` constructor expects 4 parameters, and you must provide them.  Ordinarily, you could use default values, but these parameters are all positional, and ones you want here are not the first ones.  You will have to say `super().__init__(None, nombre, None, precio)`.

Comment: @TimRoberts Or use keyword arguments instead of positional ones (after setting default values to parameters).

Comment: It is not about the attributes.  It is about the parameter list of the init constructors.  (You have to pass the arguments to the superclass init that it expects.  If you are not using them, you can pass dummy values.  (Incidentally, your sample code is missing the `class Producto:` line at the top).

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately when you inherit the parent class you get all of the attributes with it.
The way I see it you have several options:

- Give the parent class default values for fields which are "optional" and move them to the end of the attributes list.
- Add in a middle level of inheritance and update the base level to not require the 2 optional attributes.
- Set the values to "None" to just "Get it working" [ This is not preferred as it could cause unexpected behaviour ]

Answer (score 0):

You must pass all parameters that have no default value. I just show the way to make it works, not best practice.

```
class Libros(Producto):
    def __init__(self, referencia, precio, nombre_libro, nombre_autor, isbn, distribuidor):
        #Here I want to inherit only the "referencia" and "precio" attributes
        super().__init__(referencia, None, None, precio)

class Medicamentos(Producto):
    def __init__(self, nombre, precio, distribuidora, farmaceutica):
        #Here I want to inherit only the "referencia" and "precio" attributes
        super().__init__(None, nombre, None, precio)
```